# 429 (Too Many Requests) error calling Hubspot API via cors-anywhere.herokuapp

Tags: reactjs, web-applications, cors, rate-limiting, hubspot

I'm trying to build a web-application using React and for that I'm using Hubspot API to manage contacts in my account. For the HTTP request I'm using JavaScript library 'request-promise' with the proxy server: https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/

Code below:

```
do{
    //Here I'm making http request constantly
}while(process);
```

After around 100 HTTP requests, the application shows me the error:

> GET
> [https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/lists/all/contacts/all?hapikey=${hapiKey}&count=1000](https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/lists/all/contacts/all?hapikey=$%7BhapiKey%7D&count=1000)
> 429 (Too Many Requests)

https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ seems to have rate-limiting issues. Does someone has any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

429 Too Many Requests
The HTTP 429 Too Many Requests response status code indicates the user has sent too many requests in a given amount of time ("rate limiting").

A Retry-After header might be included to this response indicating how long to wait before making a new request.

Source  : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried running a server locally? https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere

Comment: Do you mean to create a server by my own? Can you explain your question please? The application should be also used by the users.

Comment: Is it possible to set rate-limiting to unlimited?

Comment: As far as I know, the cors-anywhere on heroku is not meant for production purposes, only for testing things. My answer to run it locally was meant for testing as well.

Hubapi should provide a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to allow your application to read from it. Otherwise youll never be able to read data from it. Is there an option in there where you can specify that header?